# stat_summary_hex coloured by ratio

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have a data frame with the following columns: `x, y, num, denom`, and I would like to produce a hex plot with the colours of the hexagons set by `sum(num)/sum(denom)`.

I assumed that the answer would involve `stat_summary_hex` so I naively tried:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + stat_summary_hex(fun=function(d) {sum(d$num)/sum(d$denom) })
```

but the output is:

```
Error: stat_summaryhex requires the following missing aesthetics: z
```

and I understand why (I didn't give it a `z` aesthetic), but I'm not sure what to try next: how can I pass in 2 `z` aesthetics (i.e. `num` and `denom`)?

Comment: I'll try to put together an example, but your version will result in my hexes being coloured by `sum(num/denom)` rather than `sum(num)/sum(denom)`

Comment: Yeah...I figured that out eventually. Not sure you can do this at the moment.

Comment: I don't think the `stat_summary_hex` code allows this. However, I just had a thought that is so amazingly hack-tastic that I'm actually giggling a little: create a new _character_ column with the ratio, and then write a function for stat_summary_hex that parses it, converts back to numeric and then does the calculation. Haven't even tried it to see if it works, but just typing it out kind of makes me ill.

Comment: @joran I came up with a slightly nicer hack, see below :)

Comment: Much much nicer. Well done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding a hack to do what I wanted, which I will record here:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x,y=y,z=complex(0,num,denom))) + 
  stat_summary_hex(fun= function(x) { sum(Re(x)) / sum(Im(x)) })
```

Essentially, I did provide a `z` parameter, which was a column of complex numbers. Complex numbers are numbers, so ggplot lets them through, and they have two parts, a real and an imaginary part, so the aggregation function is able to compute the ratio I wanted.

Comment: A few years later, I wonder if there is a more elegant solution to this. Additionally, I'd like to convert the z value to a factor, but ggplot defaults its scale to continuous, even though i specify a discrete fill scale later.